# What to do when run Google AppScript to check url status but results recorded 403?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-403, urlfetch

I use this function and it works for most URLs but for some URL the result in Column B shows 403. I'm not sure if it's about the user agent so I try to force to be specific user-agent. But results still 403.

```
function checkUrlsAndRecordResult() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); // Assuming URLs are in column B
  var resultColumn = sheet.getRange("B2:B"); // Column B to record results
  var results = [];

  // Define a specific Chrome User-Agent
  var chromeUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36";

  var headers = {
    "User-Agent": chromeUserAgent
  };

  var options = {
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var url = data[i][0];
    if (url) {
      try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // Fetch with custom headers and options
        var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

        // Record the result in the results array
        results.push([responseCode]);

        // You can add additional checks or error handling here if needed
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle the error gracefully
        results.push(["Error"]);
      }
    } else {
      // If there's no URL in the cell, record a blank result
      results.push(['']);
    }
  }

  // Set the results in column B
  resultColumn.setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to replicate some URL on my end too and get 403. The [HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it. Those websites might not allow Google side(Google App Script) to access it. Have you tried using another language?